# How do I fix the '@react-native-community/geolocation' linking error on IOS using Expo bare workflow?

Tags: react-native, expo, geolocation

I npm installed @react-native-community/geolocation to use on my app. I followed the documentation to give permission in the manifest file and the info.plist. It works perfectly fine on android but i get this linking error on IOS. The issue arises right when i import the library, not using yet. I am using expo bare workflow.

ERROR  Error: The package '@react-native-community/geolocation' doesn't seem to be linked. Make sure:

- You have run 'pod install'
- You rebuilt the app after installing the package
- You are not using Expo managed workflow
  , js engine: hermes
  LOG  Running "main" with {"rootTag":41,"initialProps":{}}
  ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I have ran pod install, rebuilt my app just like suggested but the issue is still there only for IOS. I have tried 2 other libraries, expo location and react-native-background-location. They both have linking issues too.